# How to solve "Failed to initialize graphics" when launching a game from Steam?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games, steam

I get this message when I run a gaming title with GE-PROTON8-15:

```
Failed to initialize graphics.
Make sure you have DirectX 11 installed, have up to date
drivers for your graphics card and have not disabled
3D acceleration in display settings.
InitializeEngineGraphics failed
```

My specs: Ubuntu 23.04, NVIDIA GTX 670 with Intel Core i5 4 gen , 16 GB RAM.

Comment: You need to add more information by [edit]ing it to your question. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of NVIDIA driver? Have you tried using another version of NVIDIA driver?

Comment: I use the lastest Ubuntu version 23.04 , I have the lastest nvidia graphic card driver

Comment: Is it any solution? Thank you!